# Unable to start X after Cheese and VLC are installed

Tags: xorg, vlc

I installed Cheese and VLC from the Raspbian repositories. The programs worked perfectly until I tried to restart the computer. Now, after executing startx I get a black screen. After killing X I see the following error message:

```
No protocol specified

waiting for X server to begin accepting connections .
No protocol specified
..
No protocol specified
.. Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Bad file descriptor
xinit: server error
```

Can anyone help me to fix this error?

Comment: Can you paste `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` please?

Comment: Are you using the standard install other than those applications you have installed?

Comment: They've been downloaded from the raspbian repositories

Comment: Have you solved this issue or has it been resolved? If so, could create a self-answer and mark it as such. We are trying to get the site Q:A ratio up, and this question appears to have been inactive for quite a while.

Answer (score 2):

Check your ~/.xinitrc file. It sounds like something listed there to be launched at execution of the startx command isn't starting properly and is hanging, making it look like X hasn't started. (It probably has, it's just showing a black background. Misleading, I know!)

Answer (score 0):

Check how much free space you have available in the partition that your home directory is located on, as X creates configuration files and temporary files in your home folder.